# It is possible to test methods that are not called from the project I have published?

Tags: weblogic, soapui

[image]

For example, I got methods from `srv-nuc-jee-GeographicSiteConsult-service` that are not called from methods of `srv-nuc-jee-PlaceServicesConsult-service`.

Can I get a path to test this methods with a WSDL in SOAP UI?